# Difference between EventEmitter vs Output Decorators in Angular-Cli

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-decorator

Why does **EventEmitter** and **Output** Decorator needs to be used together ?,
I cannot see the difference between the two,

If they are required to be used together why not just one decorator to emit as well as bind to selector wherever it is used !

Appreciate any explanation !

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EventEmitter` is just a `Subject`.

`@Output()` is what marks the field as output for Angular event binding.

I haven't tried in Angular TS, but in Angular Dart it was possible to just use a Stream (equivalent to `Subject`) instead of `EventEmitter`. 
In recent versions `EventEmitter` was removed completely in Dart Angular.
Perhaps this works in Angular TS as well.

There were plans to extends the API of `EventEmitter` in a way that might be incompatible with `Subject`, therefore a custom class was created.
But there are no signs this will actually happen.

Comment: Hi @Gunter,
Is there a way present to utilize a function by parent component with Output Decorator alone ?

Thank You

Comment: `@Output()` is to emit events that can be consumed by event binding like `(myEvent)="doSomething($event)"`. I don't understand what you mean by "utilize function by parent". Can you please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @Gunter,
I understand the difference now,
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

**EventEmitter** allows you to create a custom event, **emit** from this event and subscribe to this event, react to it.

**@Output()** allow you to spread these events to parent components :

child.Component.ts

```
  @Output() myEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

parent.component.ts

```
<app-child-component (myEvent)="reactToChildEvent($event)"></app-child-component>
```

**EDIT :**

You can use `EventEmitter` alone, without `@Ouput()`, to emit from a service to all subscribed components, or inside the same component.

Comment: Hi @Boulboulouboule,
Thanks for information !
I am aware of the functionality of each one of them,
was curious with usage of EventEmitter and Output together !
Thank You

Comment: Ok ! Note that EventEmitters can be used without @Output() decorator

Comment: `EventEmitter` is just a `Subject` (extends `Subject`) as mentioned in my answer, but it was mentioned several times by the Angular team that `EventEmitter` should not be used for anything else than for `@Output()`s because it's API might change in breaking ways without any notice. There is also no point, because you can just use `Subject` to achieve the same.